# CSS Animation: How to find out appropriate time intervals for a full screen background image animation?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe, percentile

I am following [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/) to learn how to do [this full screen background image (and title on image) slideshow](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index.html) through CSS animations.

***BACKGROUND:***

For the slideshow, they have used an `<ul>`, and in it, each of the 6 `<li>`s contains a `span` to contain the image and a `div` to contain the title on the image.

Then in CSS, both the `titleAnimation` and `imageAnimation` get an `animation-duration` of `36s` :

```
.the-slideshow li span { /*span containing image*/
  ...
  animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
```

and

```
.the-slideshow li div { /*div containing the title text*/
  ...
  animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
```

Then they set `background-image` for each span and they have applied an `animation-delay` of `6s` to the second child (`.the-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span`) of each `li`, that of `12s` to the third child, `18s` to the fourth child, `to the fifth child, and` to the sixth child of each `li`.

Then they applied the `animation-delay` with the same (as above) values to each `div` which contains the title text, starting from the second `div`( - same as above).

Then they declare the `imageAnimation` ( and `titleAnimation` in a similar way) as follows:

---

***QUESTION:***

**My question is from the following CSS and parts of the explanation shown in bold:**

```
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
        0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
        8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
        17% { opacity: 1 }
        25% { opacity: 0 }
        100% { opacity: 0 } }
```

> *Now, why those values? We want each image to be visible for 6 seconds and we know that at the end of a cycle, we want the first image to show again. We have 6 images, so we will need 36 seconds for a whole cycle to finish. Now, we need to “time” the opacity values accordingly. Knowing that our second image will start animating at 6 seconds, **we need to know at what percentile of the animation this will require the first image to fade out**.... **Dividing 6 by 36 gives us 0.166**… which would be **16% for our keyframe step**. Now, because we don’t want our image to just fade all the time, we’ll define an inbetween step, which we’ll set at half of what we calculated, i.e. 8%. That’s the point that we want to show the image completely and we only want to start fading it out at 17%, making it disappear completely at 25%.*

1. **I have read that**

> percentile is the measure that indicates what percentage of the given
>   population scored at or below the measure.

([Source Video](http://study.com/academy/lesson/finding-percentiles-in-a-data-set-formula-examples-quiz.html))

In the light of this, I do not understand the statement: *"Knowing that our second image will start animating at 6 seconds, we need to know at what percentile of the animation this will require the first image to fade out."* **So can somebody paraphrase it in a more understandable way?**

2. **Why do we divide 6 by 36**.
3. **How do we know that that is 16% of our keyframe step. What is the value of our keyframe step?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are getting this question from - maybe it's a class? But it might be easier to think of it as a whole, or even work it backwards.

But first, let me clarify one thing in your question:

> Then they set background-image for each span and they have applied an
>   animation-delay of 6s to the second child (.the-slideshow
>   li:nth-child(2) span) of each li, that of 12s to the third child, 18s
>   to the fourth child, to the fifth child, and to the sixth child of
>   each li.

This isn't completely correct. It's really 6 seconds assigned EACH child, which is the time that the animation for that child starts. This means:

```
1 (first child) = 0s
2 (second child) = 6s 
3 = 12s
4 = 18s
5 = 24s
6 = 36s
```

Now, knowing that "the percentile is the measure that indicates what percentage of the given population scored at or below the measure", can easily be thought of in terms of time -

```
"A percentile the measure that indicates what percentage of the given
[picture] population SHOWS at or below the measure."
```

We know that the image shows for 6 seconds, but it doesn't just fade in and then instantly fade out... it fades in quickly to 100%, waits, then fades out quickly. That makes me think that the question is really asking "Knowing that our second image will start animating at 6 seconds, we need to know at how long to show the image at 100% before starting to fade out."

Working the problem backwards, and using the source video for how to work a percentile, I get that 6 (number of pictures) x .17 (the percentile) = 1.02. This means that it fades in for roughly 2.5 seconds, shows at 100% for 1.02 seconds, then fades out for roughly 2.5 seconds.

> 2. Why do we divide 6 by 36?

Let me ask you... what would happen if you remove a couple of the pictures, but don't change the keyframe timing? Try to remove just the 5th and 6th picture in both the HTML and CSS. I bet you will end up getting 4 pictures that fade together very nicely, then a black screen for roughly 10 seconds. Why? Because the keyframes need to be timed for each picture.

To get the total time that is spent on a picture and making it fade in and out correctly, we take the time per picture (6) and divide it by the total time of animation (36). This gives us .16666 (17%), or the percentile that the picture shows for 100% (as explained above).

If you remove two pictures, you need to change the key framestep timing... assuming you have 4 pictures, each showing for 6 seconds then 4x6 = 24 seconds total timing. 6 (time per picture) / 24 (total time) = .25. Therefore, the picture should be at 100% up to the 25th percentile. The keyframe timing for the picture would look something like:

```
0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
13% { opacity: 1;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
25% { opacity: 1 }
38% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
```

> 3. How do we know that that is 16% of our keyframe step. What is the value of our keyframe step?

Per definition:

> A key frame in animation and filmmaking is a drawing that defines the
>   starting and ending points of any smooth transition. The drawings are
>   called "frames" because their position in time is measured in frames
>   on a strip of film.

Doing the math of 6 x .16 = .96... but let's use the value of .17 because that's what the code uses --- 6 x .17 = 1.02... we can take the time for picture x our percentage. 6 x 1.02 = 6.12. I am guessing that the keyframe value is 1.02 or 6.12.

I hope that helps.